# Google Oauth provisional API customerID fetching

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-oauth

Right now we are using Google Oauth 1.0 and we try to determine user is domain admin by doing

```
$domain = 'abc.com';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Gapps');
$gdata = new Zend_Gdata_Gapps($httpClient, $domain);
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Query');
$gquery = new Zend_Gdata_Query('https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/customer/2.0/customerId');
```

We would iterate through and see if customerId found

```
$customerId = $exattr['value'];
```

then after that we would do

```
$gquery_str = 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/orguser/2.0/'.$customerId.'?get=all';
```

to get the orgUnitPath and email.

All this work out just great but ofcourse google Oauth 1.0 is deprecate and we are force to move to new google oauth.

With new google oauth I am be able to get user information by doing

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);

$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
$plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
       $me = $plus->people->get("me");
       $test = $me->getEmails();

       echo "<pre>";
       echo var_dump($test);
       echo "</pre>";
```

How can I be able to determine customerID if directory admin and be able to achieve orgUnit just like above example?

I tried Google_Service_Directory and Google_Service_Admin

```
 $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit");
 $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
```

But not be able to fetch customerId and orgUnit.  Any example or help would be greatly appreciated.